# Pullback of effective divisor under projection map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $E$ be a vector bundle over a smooth algebraic variety $X$ and $\phi$ be a nonconstant map from a smooth curve $C$ to $X$. Let $\psi$ be the projection map from the projective bundle $\Bbb P_C(E|_C)$ to $\Bbb P(E)$. Is it true that pullback of any effective divisor under the projection map $\psi$ is also an effective divisor in $\Bbb P_C(E|_C)$?

Comment: You should add what you have tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: I note that when X is a smooth curve, then the map \psi is flat as \phi is flat. But what if I replace X by any nonsingluar higher dimensional variety.

Comment: P_C(E|C) can be thought as the fibre product

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). I've upgraded your post in this instance, and it would be good for you to learn and use MathJax on this site going forwards.